# prevent react router transitions on parent route when moving between child routes

Tags: react-router, reactcsstransitiongroup

I have set up a router with animating transitions. Is it possible to trigger transitions on child routes only rather than transitioning the whole page when the user moves from /topics/rendering to /topics/components. Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/r0PvB30wk

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { CSSTransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group'

import About from './components/About'
import Home from './components/Home'
import Topics from './components/Topics'

import './styles.css'

const Topic = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
  </div>
);

const Topics = ({ match }) => (
  <div className="page">
    <h2>Topics</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>
          Rendering with React
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>
          Components
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>
          Props v. State
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <Route path={`${match.url}/:topicId`} component={Topic} />
    <Route
      exact
      path={match.url}
      render={() => <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>}
    />
  </div>
);

export default Topics;
const BasicExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <Route render={({ location, history, match }) => (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
        </ul>

        <hr />
        <CSSTransitionGroup
          transitionEnterTimeout={500}
          transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
          transitionName="fade"
        >
          <Switch key={location.key} location={location}>
            <Route exact path="/"       component={Home}   location={location} key={location.key} />
            <Route       path="/about"  component={About}  location={location} key={location.key} />
            <Route       path="/topics" component={Topics} location={location} key={location.key} />
          </Switch>
        </CSSTransitionGroup>
      </div>
    )}/>
  </Router>
)

render(<BasicExample />, document.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could achieve the result was to detect if I was changing from parent to parent or child to child route and turn off the transition based on that.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CSSTransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';

import About  from './components/About';
import Home   from './components/Home';
import Topics from './components/Topics';

import './styles.css';

var currentRoute = ''

const getParentPathname = pathname => 
  pathname === '/'
    ? ''
    : (/([a-zA-Z])([^/]*)/).exec(pathname)[0]

class BasicExample extends Component {
  render = () =>
    <Router>
      <Route
        render={({ location, history, match }) => {

          const nextRoute = getParentPathname(location.pathname)
          const isAnimated = 
                !currentRoute.includes(nextRoute) || 
                !nextRoute.includes(currentRoute)
          currentRoute = nextRoute

          return(
            <div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/askdjhakshd">Unknown</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>

              <hr />
              <CSSTransitionGroup
                transitionEnter={isAnimated}
                transitionLeave={isAnimated}
                transitionEnterTimeout={500}
                transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
                transitionName="fade"
              >
                {/* switch will render the 1st route that matches */}
                <Switch key={location.key} location={location}>
                  <Route exact path="/"       component={Home}   location={location} key={location.key}/>
                  <Route       path="/about"  component={About}  location={location} key={location.key}/>
                  <Route       path="/topics" component={Topics} location={location} key={location.key}/>
                  <Route render={props => <p>Unknown Route</p>}/>
                </Switch>
              </CSSTransitionGroup>
            </div> 
          )

        }
      }/>
    </Router>

}

render(<BasicExample />, document.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

I headed the same problem, so I wrote the module solving this.

https://github.com/melounek/switch-css-transition-group

This `SwitchCSSTransitionGroup` component is detecting if routes inside are really switching (based on `react-router.matchPath`) and then changing the Switch key approprietly.

So you can update this code-snippet and it should work:

```js
    ...
    <SwitchCSSTransitionGroup
      transitionEnterTimeout={500}
      transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
      transitionName="fade"
      location={location}>
        <Route exact path="/"       component={Home}   location={location} key={location.key} />
        <Route       path="/about"  component={About}  location={location} key={location.key} />
        <Route       path="/topics" component={Topics} location={location} key={location.key} />
    </SwitchCSSTransitionGroup>
    ...
```